# Python(Google Colaboratory). Пример из книжки по DL - KeyError: ' '

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Никак не могу понять почему индекс пустой. Может не в индексе дело?

```
    import numpy as np
    from google.colab import files

    uploaded = files.upload()

    # читаем файл

    START_CHAR = '\b'   # будет подставляться перед началом предложения
    END_CHAR = '\t'     # после его конца
    PADDING_CHAR = '\a' #будет заполнять остаток предложения до максимума длины
    chars = set( [START_CHAR, '\n', END_CHAR] )
    #with open(uploaded, 'r') as f:
    for line in str(uploaded.values()):
       chars.update( list(line.strip().lower()) )
    #print('chars', chars)
    char_indices = { c : i for i,c in enumerate(sorted(list(chars)) )}  #sorted(
    char_indices[PADDING_CHAR] = 0
    indices_to_chars = { i : c for c,i in char_indices.items() }

    num_chars = len(chars)
   )


    # Дальше создадим векторные представления для символов; это будет просто one-hot 
    # представление, в котором каждый символ представляется вектором с одной единицей

    def get_one(i, sz):
        res = np.zeros(sz)
        res[i] = 1
        return res

    char_vectors = {
        c : (np.zeros(num_chars) if c == PADDING_CHAR else get_one(v, num_chars))
        for c,v in char_indices.items()
    }

    # Дальше прочитаем входной файл еще раз, теперь уже деля его на предложения
    # и выписывая их отдельно.


    sentence_end_markers = set( '.!?' )

    sentences = []
    current_sentence = ''

    for line in str(uploaded.values()):   
          s = line.lower()
          if len(s) > 0:
             current_sentence += s # + 1   
          if s in sentence_end_markers:
             current_sentence = current_sentence.strip('.!?')
             if len(current_sentence) > 15:
                current_sentence += s + "\n"
                sentences.append(str(current_sentence))
                current_sentence = ''
             print('current_sentence.strip', sentences)
     # Следующий шаг — векторизация. Давайте определим процедуру, которая превращает
     # набор предложений в два тензора: X содержит векторы символов, а y — результат,
     # который нам нужно предсказать
    def get_matrices(sentences):

                max_sentence_len = np.max([ len(x) for x in sentences ])
                X = np.zeros((len(sentences), max_sentence_len, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool) # для ускорения и экономии памяти
                y = np.zeros((len(sentences), max_sentence_len, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool) # для ускорения и экономии памяти
                for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
                  char_seq = (START_CHAR + sentence + END_CHAR).ljust(max_sentence_len+1, PADDING_CHAR)
                  for t in range(max_sentence_len):
                    X[i, t, :] = char_vectors[char_seq[t]]
                    y[i, t, :] = char_vectors[char_seq[t+1]]
                return X,y  





    # один уровень LSTM-ячеек, результаты которых  
    # пропускаются через один полносвязный слой, и тут же происходит классификация.


    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, TimeDistributed, Activation  
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(output_dim=128, activation='tanh',
        return_sequences=True, input_dim=num_chars))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim=num_chars))) 
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    from keras.optimizers import Adam
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(clipnorm=1.), metrics=['accuracy'])







    # функцию-генератор, порождающую минибатчи один за другим

    test_indices = np.random.choice(range(len(sentences)), int(len(sentences) * 0.05))


    sentences_train = [ sentences[x] for x in set(range(len(sentences))) - set(test_indices) ]
    sentences_test = [ sentences[x] for x in test_indices]
    sentences_train = sorted(sentences_train, key = lambda x : len(x))
    X_test, y_test = get_matrices(sentences_test)
    batch_size = 16
    def generate_batch():
       while True:
            for i in range( int(len(sentences_train) / batch_size) ):
               sentences_batch = sentences_train[ i*batch_size : (i+1)*batch_size ]
               yield get_matrices(sentences_batch)


    # две стандартные функции обратного вызова
    from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger
    cb_sampler = CharSampler(char_vectors, model)
    cb_logger = CSVLogger('sin_l/' + model_fname + '.log')


    # порождение нескольких текстов в виде еще одной функции обратного вызова.


    from keras.callbacks import Callback
    class CharSampler(Callback):
         def __init__(self, char_vectors, model):
             self.char_vectors = char_vectors
             self.model = model
         def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
             self.epoch = 0
             if os.path.isfile(output_fname):
                os.remove(output_fname)
         def sample( self, preds, temperature=1.0):
             preds = np.asarray(preds).astype('float64')
             preds = np.log(preds) / temperature
             exp_preds = np.exp(preds)
             preds = exp_preds / np.sum(exp_preds)
             probas = np.random.multinomial(1, preds, 1)
             return np.argmax(probas)
         def sample_one(self, T):
             result = START_CHAR
             while len(result)<500:
                 Xsampled = np.zeros( (1, len(result), num_chars) )
                 for t,c in enumerate( list( result ) ):
                    Xsampled[0,t,:] = self.char_vectors[ c ]
                 ysampled = self.model.predict( Xsampled, batch_size=1 )[0,:]
                 yv = ysampled[len(result)-1,:]
                 selected_char = indices_to_chars[ self.sample( yv, T ) ]
                 if selected_char==END_CHAR: 
                    break
                 result = result + selected_char
             return result
         def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
             self.epoch = self.epoch+1
             if self.epoch % 50 == 0:
                print("\nEpoch %d text sampling:" % self.epoch)
                with open( output_fname, 'a' ) as outf:
                     outf.write( '\n===== Epoch %d =====\n' % self.epoch )
                     for T in [0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1]:
                         print('\tsampling, T = %.1f...' % T)
                         for _ in range(5):
                             self.model.reset_states()
                             res = self.sample_one(T)
                             outf.write( '\nT = %.1f\n%s\n' % (T, res[1:]) )                



    model.fit_generator( generate_batch(),
       int(len(sentences_train) / batch_size) * batch_size,
       nb_epoch=1000, verbose=True, validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
       callbacks=[cb_logger, cb_sampler, cb_checkpoint] )
```

Выдает:

```
lt1.txt(text/plain) - 442059 bytes, last modified: 27.05.2018 - 100% done
 Saving lt1.txt to lt1 (2).txt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4b86f59567ae> in <module>()
    111 sentences_test = [ sentences[x] for x in test_indices]
    112 sentences_train = sorted(sentences_train, key = lambda x : len(x))
--> 113 X_test, y_test = get_matrices(sentences_test)
    114 batch_size = 16
    115 def generate_batch():

<ipython-input-2-4b86f59567ae> in get_matrices(sentences)
     74               for t in range(max_sentence_len):
     75                 X[i, t, :] = char_vectors[char_seq[t]]
---> 76                 y[i, t, :] = char_vectors[char_seq[t+1]]
     77             return X,y
     78 

KeyError: ' '
```

Comment: Неужели никто не может помочь?

Comment: Ну проще всего какую-нибудь отладочную печать там сделать, поймав ошибку. Посмотреть, чему равно t в этот момент, чему равно char_seq[t+1], что вообще есть в char_seq и в char_vectors. Я так понимаю, в char_vectors нет ключа ' ' и вот так со стороны сложно понять, почему его там нет и что там вообще должно быть.

Comment: У меня такая же проблема, ты не нашел ответ?